# How do I initialize IKImageView?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ikimageview

I am completely stumped with this one: I'm new to Xcode, coming from Windows. I create a brand new Cocoa app, place an IKImageView in Interface Builder, save and launch the app. Xcode shows the app icon bouncing forever, never launching. If I trace into it I get application crash right away.

I've downloaded examples from Apple but I cannot see how they initialize IKImageView, if that's what I'm failing to do. I've been searching for a solution for hours. Help?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are not including the required frameworks that are used by IKImageView. Just follow the instructions that are found in the [Image Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/ImageKitComponents/ImageKitComponents.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004907-CH3-SW1), in particular the section labeled Using the Image Kit in Xcode and you should have no problems.